# Repositorio de clases en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, repositorio, modelos

estoy desarrollando tres proyectos, los cuales son independientes pero comparten ciertas entidades. Todos apuntan a la misma base de datos. Para trabajar con estas entidades cada una tiene una clase Model, donde están sus getter y setters además de otros métodos propios de la clase.

En vista a actualizaciones de esos modelos, tendría que duplicar el código y realizar cambios por cada proyecto. Mi pregunta es, ¿Hay posibilidad de crear un repositorio de clases, instalable con artisan o composer (instalable y actualizable claro) para poder realizar el cambio de código en dicho repositorio y se aplicase con un comando a cada uno de los proyectos por consola? Por ejemplo, añado en la clase modelo Usuarios del repositorio un método getEmail() y luego en cada consola de cada proyecto ejecutar al ejecutar composer update traería esos nuevos cambios.

Espero haberme explicado bien, y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Suena a un paquete de composer más que a un repositorio

Comment: Por ejemplo, como bien dices, un paquete de composer.

Comment: Sí, es posible. Con composer podés instalar/actualizar el paquete en todos tus proyectos desde un repositorio git directamente

Comment: Muchas gracias!!